# downloaded png image with transparent background shows with black background

Tags: android, image, bitmap, imageview, bitmapimage

In my android application I downloaded some png image and write them in sd card. when I show them in image view they are showing with black background. the original images have transparent  background. How I can keep the background transparent. Please help me. I use PNG format to compress and write it to sd card

Comment: you have to set R.color.Transparent for imageview

Comment: Thanks for reply. yes I did this. I did just now One more thing, I set canvas color android.R.color.transparent and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Set The View Background as

```
R.color.transparent
```

or in xml like

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Edited :

Thanks for reply. yes I did this. I did just now One more thing, I set canvas color android.R.color.transparent and it worked